# Is there a website on which I can write and display MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

MathJax is used in displaying math equations and expressions more elegantly. I've seen it most widely used in the mathematics department of StackExchange. What I am inquiring about is if there is a site that is used solely for the purpose of writing MathJax code and displaying its translation. I would like to show a person my custom example using MathJax, but I don't know of any way of showing it to him. What would be ideal is if I could give him a URL that takes him to a site showing the content I've written in MathJax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [mathjax.org](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/) perhaps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the website you are looking for:

http://mathb.in/

Edit:
This website I actually like better: http://www.texpaste.com/. It is a sort of github gists for latex. You have the ability to manage your saved mathjax notes.

Comment: After literally over a year I finally get what I need. Thanks!